# ECMAScript : hex key and memory size

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hex, key

I need to store entries in a Map,refering other entries :

```
class Entry {
  constructor() {
    this.letter = ''
    this.related = new Map()
  }
}

class Trie {
  constructor() {
    this.entries = new Map()
  }
}
```

what's better to store Entries in the trie :

- using string keys (eg: 'a1b2c3d4')
- or using hex keys: eg: 0xa1b2c3d4

I guess the hex number is the best solution. How to produce such hex keys (8 digits)

You can refer to the github repo : hefeust/ecmasy for implementation details.

Thanks.

Comment: In JavaScript, a number is a number, always 64-bit floating point. You can use hex to express the value in code, but internally it's still a floating-point value.

Comment: so it takes less memory than a 8-character string... it's ok. Thanks you.

Comment: Since JavaScript numbers are doubles, they don't have 64 bits of precision. You cannot represent an arbitrary 64-bit value as a JS number, so you will end up confusing similar large numbers.